# As a US citizen, can I work for my Canadian university without a study permit from the US?

Tags: research-assistantship, visa, canada

This is probably a fairly unique situation and I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask here, but I'm currently finishing up my master's at a university in Quebec, but I no longer live in Quebec as I have no more classes to take and I'd rather be in the US for various reasons. My thesis advisor, however, wants to contract me as a research assistant for work that I can do even while I'm in the US.

The problem is that my study permit expired about a month ago and I'm not sure he'll be allowed to contract me unless I have a permit, even though I don't need the permit to finish up my degree since I'm not actually living in the Canada. I can probably renew the permit, but now that the expiration passed, it would cost me $350, which is hard to swallow considering that that would take up the first two weeks of pay.

So, are study permits required in this situation? Is there another type of permit I could get instead? Do I need a permit at all since I won't be stepping foot in Canada?

(I would call CIC directly to ask about this, but for some reason their 800 number does not accept calls from the US. I have not been able to find any way to directly contact CIC from the US.)

Comment: Without a study or work permit they might not be able to pay you. If you check http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/apply-who-nopermit.asp under "Short-term researcher", you might be eligible to work for up to 4 months without a work permit, but you would need to check this. The best place to contact is probably the Canadian Embassy or Consulate closest to your location.

Comment: OP, in paragraph two, did you mean "since I'm not actually living in *Canada*"?

Comment: Employing someone who lives and works outside the employer's country creates a load of issues. Which set of laws apply to e.g. overtime? How are taxes handled? Which currency? It is possible that your university will not want to deal with those issues, and will only employ people living in Canada.

Comment: Has the university got an "international office" or something of the kind?  They are likely to be well informed on such matters and might be more helpful than the government agency.